# Custom date format in KQL

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I would like to know if there is a possibility to customize the format of a specific datetime in KQL.

For example I have the following code:

```
let value = format_datetime(datetime(07:30:00), "HH:mm");
print value
```

As a result we obtain 07:30

My question here is that instead of having 07:30, is there a possibility to format it in a way to have a value = **7hr 30m**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on if your input is a `datetime` or a `timespan` value, you can try either of the following options (using some string manipulation):

```
print ts = timespan(07:30:00)
| project output = strcat(toint(ts/1h), "hr ", toint(ts/1m)%60, "min")

print dt = datetime(2021-02-16 07:30:00)
| project output = strcat(datetime_part("hour", dt), "hr ", datetime_part("minute", dt), "min")
```